# Flutter SDK 0.0.0-unknown [xcrun: error: invalid active developer path] after MacOS Ventura update

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I upgraded my software yesterday to MacOS Ventura. Today when I opened my project so I can work on it, I cannot get to build the app because I get this error: The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in elfi_menu...
The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.

Because country_icons 2.0.2 requires Flutter SDK version >=0.1.4 and no versions of country_icons match >2.0.2 <3.0.0, country_icons ^2.0.2 is forbidden.
So, because elfi_menu depends on country_icons ^2.0.2, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because elfi_menu depends on country_icons ^2.0.2, version solving failed.)
Exited (1)
```

I have tried to reinstall flutter, I get the same error, I also tried opening a new project, same error. I also looked it up on the internet but I saw pretty old similar issues, they are fixing it on Windows and it is not the same here on mac from what I've seen.

Does anyone have any ideas why this happened and how to fix it?

Thank you very much in advance

EDIT

Above the output I have written in the code, this is a line that appeared:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

I searched for the solve on the internet and this like solves the problem, written in the terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, I have written this in the terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

- Open Xcode
- Go to Preferences
- Go to Locations
- Use the "Command Line Tools" dropdown to select the available Command Line Tools

Mine was empty and I chose the single available option: "Xcode 14.0.1 (...)"

Restart console, everything should be working